# How does it work to implement an API for Payments in separate ends of a project?

Tags: asp.net, angular, api

Alright, A friend and I are developing an App where I'm developing the back-end and he is developing the front-end. The project is separated into two repositories the front-end and the back-end, and we need to implement a payment API.

Now, since we're using the REST API Concept, we communicate both ends through JSON data.

My question is, when we're making the connection to the payment API, who needs to execute that request? The front-end or the back-end?

I know it's a silly question, but first timer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backend will obviously process the payment, I'm not sure which payment API you're going to use. But depending on the API you go with, the implementation will vary. But the actual processing of the payment will be processed in the backend for sure.

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on the API.

In some cases, a payment can be accomplished via a secure web service call, which would be issued by your friend's REST service. The front end will still need to collect data (e.g. payment amount and card number) and may also need to collect additional information to satisfy the API (e.g. IP address or browser signature, for risk management purposes).

In other cases, the payment is sent directly to the service from the browser. The role of your application would be to render an iFrame housing a page that is reached via SSO. The back end may need to call a service to retrieve an SSO token, or may have to compute an SSO token using a shared key.

You should probably refer to the payment API's documentation. They often have very specific guidance which you must follow carefully in order to achieve payment card (PCI-DSS) compliance.  There is nothing special about "payments" that says that allows StackOverflow users to guess anything about its API.